# Cannot start sshd service: Failed to start openssh.service: Unit not found

Tags: ssh, rhel7

On a virtual rhel 7.4 I'm getting a weird error when trying to start the sshd service.

> Failed to start openssh.service: Unit not found

In fact, I get the same error when trying anything on sshd - enable, status or stop

[image: openssh picture]

I did try to restart the instance but nothing seems to work.

Comment: can you start other services ? is it just ssh ? and is the package installed correctly ? (e.g. yum reinstall openssh)

Comment: yes, I can start any other services and afaik the package is installed correctly as yum reinstall openssh runs without errors

Comment: I am pretty sure the service name is only "sshd" and not "openssh"

Comment: @TimHaegele systemctl enable sshd.service throws the same error

Comment: do you see the service using systemctl list-units --type service --all ?

Comment: or just : systemctl list-unit-files --type service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you can run the OpenSSH server, you must *install* it, but you haven't actually installed it. To fix the problem, install the OpenSSH server.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install openssh-server
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssh-server.x86_64 0:7.4p1-16.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package           Arch      Version           Repository                  Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 openssh-server    x86_64    7.4p1-16.el7      rhel-7-server-beta-rpms    458 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 458 k
Installed size: 971 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
openssh-server-7.4p1-16.el7.x86_64.rpm                     | 458 kB   00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : openssh-server-7.4p1-16.el7.x86_64                           1/1 
  Verifying  : openssh-server-7.4p1-16.el7.x86_64                           1/1 

Installed:
  openssh-server.x86_64 0:7.4p1-16.el7                                          

Complete!
```

The service is enabled by default, but if you do need to manage it, the systemd unit name is `sshd`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start sshd
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-03-24 17:37:23 EDT; 41s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 1373 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─1373 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Mar 24 17:37:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server dae...
Mar 24 17:37:23 localhost.localdomain sshd[1373]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0...
Mar 24 17:37:23 localhost.localdomain sshd[1373]: Server listening on :: port...
Mar 24 17:37:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I first tried, just that when I start or status the sshd service I get the "Failed to start openssh.service: Unit not found" error

Comment: @CatHariss Again, you need to use the correct name.

Answer (score 4):

These days, the service seems to be called `ssh`, not `sshd`:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

(this is for the `openssh-server` package version `1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5` installed via APT on Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me on Ubuntu 22

Comment: I have changed the port configuration and it's not taken after the restart, even with restart ssh